# How can I modify API so user can login with email and registration field as well?

Tags: laravel, api, laravel-7

I want that users can login with the registration number assigned to them or email. I have working api which only login users with email

```
public $successStatus = 200;

public function login(){ 
    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => request('email'), 'password' => request('password')])){ 
        $user = Auth::user(); 
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
        return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus); 
    } 
    else{ 
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: @ehmad11 but I want with both email and registration

Comment: Are you storing registration number in user table while registration?

Comment: @IrshadKhan yes

Comment: What are  you using for api authentication like jwt or passport?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the value of the `email` in your `request` parameter to determine if an `email` or `number` has been provided and then attempt to log in your user that way.

```
public function login()
{
  // determine if the value of the `email` field in the request
  // is a valid `email` or not
  $identity = filter_var(request('email'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ? 'email' : 'number';
  
  // use the value of $identity for specifying the field,
  // to compare against the value of the `email` in the request
  if (Auth::attempt([$identity => request('email'), 'password' => request('password']))) {
    $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyApp')-> accessToken; 
    return response()->json(['success' => $success], $this-> successStatus); 
  }

  return response()->json(['error'=>'Unauthorised'], 401);
}
```